# String representation of a number

Tags: java

So I was asked this question in a recent interview. There are two numbers, really large and thus they are represented as Strings. Now write a function to multiply them and come up with a resultant String.

This was the solution, I managed to come up with, but I think it's an impossible problem.

I'm using `Integer` for example.

```
public String multiply(String str1, String str2){
     int count = 0;
     for(int i=0; i < str1.length(); i++){
       int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1.substring(str1.length()-2 -i, str2.length()-1-i));
        for(int j=0; j < str2.length(); j++){
         int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2.substring(str2.length()-1 -j, str2.length()-1);
          count+= num1*num2;
        }
     }
   return String.valueOf(count);
}
```

However, I feel that since the premise of the problem is that the numerical values of the two strings cannot be stored in a variable then the variable `count` will also overflow. Thus I think my solution is incorrect. Is there a way to do this. The numbers are beyond the scope of Long or any possible numeric type available.

Comment: This is actually a tricky question. You need to apply the actual multiply algorithm treating each character in the string as a number like you do it manually on a piece of paper.

Comment: Your solution is indeed incorrect, and there is indeed a correct possible solution. Check out the implementation of BigInteger.multiply() in the JDK source code or [this article](https://silentmatt.com/blog/2011/10/how-bigintegers-work-part-2-multiplication) describing how it works.

Comment: If you're allowed to use BigInteger, then it becomes easy. Otherwise do as svasa suggested.

Comment: You might be able to use the BigInteger class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: the complexity is O ( N ^ 2 ) for the "manual" aproach. Better is to use an exotic algorithm such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you could use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` for something like this...

```
final String number1 = "12345678902374287346293649376492342...";
final String number2 = "12345678902374287346293649376492342...";
final BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(number1).multiply(new BigDecimal(number2));
System.out.println("Huge Number: " + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of "big integers" is very well handled by a number of programming languages and libraries, such as the [BigInteger class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/java_math_biginteger.htm). In terms of implementing it yourself, there are different ways to approach the problem, depending on what your needs are (e.g. computational efficiency vs. storage efficiency).

The basic idea is to break the arithmetic down into manageable chunks, just like arithmetic you probably learned in school. If you're storing the number in decimal as a string of digits, then you'd simply do digit-by-digit decimal multiplication, starting at the least significant digit (probably the right-hand end). If the result of any digit multiplication is 10 or more, you carry the extra ten(s) across and add it to the calculation of the next digit.

There are some example implementations here: [An interview question - implement Biginteger Multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209625/an-interview-question-implement-biginteger-multiply)

Answer (score 0):

Using `BigDecimal` multiply method it rather a simple answer to this question.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `BigDecimal`, you can follow the comment provided by @svasa.
You should consider the count to be a `String` as well.

From my experience they want you to implement the multiplication algorithm much like the one you were taught in elementary school.

Answer (score 0):

the complexity is O ( N ^ 2 ) for the "manual" aproach. Better is to use an exotic algorithm such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm or peek an existing class from your base class library (java / C# or whatever .. such as BigInteger)

Comment: It's not always better to use an "exotic" algorithm with better complexity. It depends on the sizes of the numbers.

Comment: It's also not technically n^2 but rather nm.

Comment: Also nobody would come up with this in an interview

Comment: :D i was saying about Big O notation ... Let N be the size of ANY number that can be multiplied with whatever secondly one ...

Comment: @James K Polk: He said that the problem he faced in the interview was to deal with big numbers ... (really large ones as he said). I am afraid that we have only two options: use classes in BCL or implement one by himself

Comment: Well, yeah. I'm not saying yours is incorrect but not as tight. My understanding is in industry (and so interviews) O() is preferred to be as tight as possible more like Theta(). By the strict def of O() your algo is also O(N^N) no matter how useless the fact is. So, since the post doesn't mention strings of equal size, *I'd* note the difference and give it as O(NM) or O(N^2) : N = max(n, m). Maybe I'm just being anal.

Answer (score 0):

They want String, which is circumstantial, but you can decompose, till they loose interest.

```
String multiply(String x, String y) {
    String sum = "0";
    String pow10 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
        char digit = x.charAt(x.length() - 1 - i);
        String term = multiplyDigit(digit, y);
        sum = add(sum, term + pow10);
        pow10 += "0";
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And so on: add, multiplyDigit.

The choice of data: char arrays, maybe digit values (byte), StringBuilder (flexible length) order and such is not really helpful for a quick implementation here (in java that is).

You could spare yourself much juggling by simplification as:

```
String multiplyDigit(char c, String x) {
    String carries = "0";
    String term = "";

    int cvalue = c - '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
        char digit = x.charAt(x.length() - 1 - i);

        int product = cvalue * (digit - '0');
        char carry = (char)('0' + (product / 10));
        char t = (char)('0' + (product % 10));
        carries = carry + carries;
        term = t + term; 
    }
    return add(carries, term);
}
```

where you do not add the carry immediately, but reuse `add(String, String)`.